# Helm install Jenkins charts failed

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

I try to install Jenkins from https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts:

```
helm repo update
helm install mot-jenkins jenkins/jenkins -f values-dev.yaml --dry-run
```

I got:

```
coalesce.go:286: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for jenkins.controller.initScripts (map[])
coalesce.go:286: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for jenkins.controller.image (map[pullPolicy:Always registry:docker.io repository:jenkins/jenkins tagLabel:jdk17])
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: jenkins/templates/tests/jenkins-test.yaml:34:24: executing "jenkins/templates/tests/jenkins-test.yaml" at <.Values.controller.image.registry>: can't evaluate field registry in type interface {}
```

The previous version of Jenkins chart with the same value yaml  worked correctly

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your configuration:

> controller.image, controller.tag, and controller.tagLabel have been removed.

[Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/e2c14505528d6b0308761282c4aad38459d21363/charts/jenkins/UPGRADING.md) you can view more details.

Answer (score 0):

As per the link https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/blob/e2c14505528d6b0308761282c4aad38459d21363/charts/jenkins/UPGRADING.md
you need to update your values yaml file with following details:

```
image: 
    registry: 
    tag: 
    pullPolicy: Always
admin:
    password:
```

Please follow the documentation for more details, which should ideally resolve this issue.